# Can I use Windows' minidump files to implement "save"/"restore" in my game?

Tags: windows, crash-dumps

I'm about to implement a save/load functionality in my game, and thought to maybe use Windows' minidump files to achieve this.

I have no experience in that, so any help would be appreciated. Is it even possible? Can a running application be "revived" from a (mini)dump file?

From a few answers already posted, it seems possible to store game state in dump file, so I'll refine the question: How much "glue" will I have to put in to recreate the things I can't store in the dump file?

Comment: No, it's a minefield. Not recommended.

Comment: There is no facility for "reviving" a process from a dump file. It is not possible for many reasons, Thomas's answer below being one. Another being that the user may have patched the operating system in the meantime, rendering the dump file useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minidump saves all virtual memory and the CPU state of your application. So far, it seems possible to restore everything from the dump. But it's not true, because handle information is missing: while the handle *value* is part of your application's memory, the *object* behind the handle (a kernel mode object) has been freed or reassigned. This means that the following cannot be restored:

- Threads
- Process
- files and directories
- Registry keys
- Windows
- Events

You would need to reassign those kernel resources - and to do so you would need to implement a (signed) kernel mode driver.
Before you consider to implement a kernel mode driver, I would suggest to think about a different way of saving and loading your application state.

Comment: My game is a very complex one, and game/simulation state is a few thousands objects big. Of course kernel drivers are hard to implement, but most of my (any) application is pure logic, and not the objects you specified. I refined my question to focus on the exact aspect of your answer: How much "glue" I have to put in to recreate the things I can't store in the dump file?

Comment: The objects I was talking about are kernel mode objects, not objects of your simulation. Most programming languages have libraries for saving objects or object trees.

Answer (score 2):

As stated here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Minidump files are used for debugging purpose. You can maybe recreate your game context from those files ... but ... Why didn't you write your own file format ?

Comment: It's a new feature, so devtime-wise this solution may be cheaper. No?

Comment: I don't know, but, are you sure that you can choose where those kind of files are stored?

Comment: @liorda you save dev time in creating the dump file but you will lose it a thousand times over trying to recover your game state from the dump file. This is like using the page file as your save game format. Sure the information is in there but good luck finding it.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you please explain the difficulties?

Comment: @liorda You have a dump file with data in it. You now need to extract the data and restore them to your data structures. This is basically the work as the "load' part of a "save/load" module, except harder because you first have to go find the data.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to use the [Recovery and Restart](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Application-Restart-and-Recovery-on-Windows-7-in-Native-Code/) framework.  In a nutshell, when your app crashes, you are given the opportunity to serialize any information that you would need when the application is restarted.